# Microsoft Click-Once and Obfuscated DLLs

Tags: deployment, clickonce, obfuscation

I have a Windows Form application that deploys using Microsoft Click-Once. I would like to add a new feature to the application that in part utilizes a third-party DLL that happens to be obfuscated.  During an initial test release of the application, the application wouldn't install.  Initial research seems to indicate that Microsoft Click-Once and Obfuscated DLLs don't play well together.  Is that the case?  If not, is there a special way to get an Obfuscated DLL to install/work in a Microsoft Click-Once deployment?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. What's your obfuscation software? 2. Please add your installation error text here

Comment: This is a pretty general question - presumably you could ask the vendor of the third-party DLL for assistance?

Comment: Sergey, the error message we were seeing is:  "Cannot load internal manifest from component file."